# How to send SMS without opening the SMS app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Can I send to Windows Phone SMS directly , rather than through the SMS application?

I've already written a function to send through the app

```
public async void SendSms(string phone, string message)
{
    var chatMessage = new ChatMessage();
    if (phone != null)
    {
        chatMessage.Recipients.Add(phone);
    }
    chatMessage.Body = message;
    await ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(chatMessage);
}
```

Now, I want to send SMS is not through the standard application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible using the native Windows Phone SDK, because the philosopy "user first" don't permit this behavior. You must see the SMS app before sending any SMS. You must use an external service via http to get what you want.